# Load view with button click on a new page MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

What is the best way or possible java script  to make it possible for me to load a view(the article) when clicking on the main page which contains the Posts.

Most docs i found load the view on a div in the same view.

Posts View:

```
<div class="row small-up-2 medium-up-3">
    @foreach (var post in Model.Posts)
    {
            <div class="column column-block">
                <div class="blog-post">
                    <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/400/cba" alt="">
                    <h3>@post.Title</h3>
                    <img src=@post.Image alt="">

                    <button data-url='@Url.Action("SearchPartial","Blog", @post.Title )'
                            class="button js-reload-details">
                        Reload
                    </button>
                </div>
        </div>
    }
```

Controller to load the article view:

```
public ActionResult SearchPartial(String title)
        {
            var model = db.Posts.Where(x => x.Title == title).FirstOrDefault();


            return View("SearchPartial", model);
        }
```

Comment: Please describe your question a little bit more. Why are you passing the title instead of ID?

Comment: Are you looking to open the article in its own page, or within a section of the page your "grid" is on?

Comment: @GrandpaGuru  cause I created a view model with no I'd, and I think the title is gonna be unique, and since it's gonna be on the nav url too

Comment: @krillgar i wanna load it on its own page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a button, use the native behavior of the HTML elements, and use an anchor tag. They are designed to send you to a new location, and will be able to easily hit your Controller and move the browser to another location.

With CSS, you can easily make them look like other buttons. I'll add classes that are a part of Bootstrap.

Also, you should send the ID of your post instead of the title. That is a unique value, and most likely, you don't have the same constraint on your Title property. Titles are fine to *search* by, however you shouldn't count on those as pointing to one and only one Post.

```
<div class="row small-up-2 medium-up-3">
    @foreach (var post in Model.Posts)
    {
        <div class="column column-block">
            <div class="blog-post">
                <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/400/cba" alt="">
                <h3>@post.Title</h3>
                <img src=@post.Image alt="">

                // Send the post.Id instead of post.Title
                <a href='@Url.Action("SearchPartial","Blog", new { id = @post.Id } )' class="btn btn-primary">
                    Reload
                </a>
            </div>
    </div>
}
```

With the change in parameter to the link, you'll need to change your action method as well.

```
public ActionResult SearchPartial(int postId)
{
    var model = db.Posts.Find(postId);

    return View("SearchPartial", model);
}
```

Comment: It's working thanks, but i got a question. When i call the searchpartial in the controller, the database searches for a title, but the returned result of is null:            Post model = db.Posts.Where(x => x.Title == title).FirstOrDefault(); the database contains a post with that title. i don't know what can cause this

Comment: As was mentioned in the comments on your question, you should search by Id instead, as it is easy to have duplicate titles. Also, you could take a look at the string that is sent. There still might be URL encodings that keep it from being an exact match to what you have in the database.

Comment: Noticed when i replaced the title with the ID the url sent to the controller is always Blog/SearchPartial the id isn't sent. When i write it myself the view loads perfectly, what can be the problem,.

Comment: You need an object with the property named the same as your Action parameter. Sorry I missed that before.

Comment: weird i get an error saying to remove the <a> tag after putting the thingy new{id=@post.Id} like you've stated

Comment: did you find the bug on it too?